# Unwind segues with programmatically created view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, programmatically-created, unwind-segue, childviewcontroller

I have a view controller (`PhotoViewController`) which has a child view controller (`CameraViewController`). In `CameraViewController`, there is a button that sets off a chain of segueing through other programmatically created view controllers. On the last of these view controllers, I want to unwind to the original `PhotoViewController`. All examples I have found require you to have view controllers in the storyboard, which I don't have. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't use segues, including an unwind segue without a storyboard. You will need to write the appropriate code to dismiss the various view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not understood what an unwind segue *is*. It is merely a way of reversing the calls that created the current view controller and got it into the view controller hierarchy, in the special case where you want to trigger this through a segue in a storyboard.

- For example, if you (or the storyboard) called `pushViewController` (for a pushed view controller), an unwind segue is just a way of calling `popViewController`.
- Or, if you called (or the storyboard) called `present` (for a modally presented view controller), an unwind segue is just a way of calling `dismiss`.

If you *don't* have your view controllers in a storyboard, you don't *need* an unwind segue; you just do one of those two things, directly, in code.

Remember, we all got along for *years* just fine without unwind segues. In fact, we all got along for years without storyboards! And so can you.

Answer (score 0):

If your original PhotoViewController is created on a storyboard and you want to segue back to it from a programmatically made VC you have present it rather than unwinding because unwindSegues are for storyboards only.

To present your PhotoViewController here is one of the ways to do so.

```
func presentPhotoViewController() {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil)
if let photoViewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoViewControllerUniqueId") as? PhotoViewController {
    // Pass any data you have (Optional)
    self.present(photoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // If your PhotoViewController is embeded in a navigation Controller do the following.
     //let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: photoViewController)
     //self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}